# First training epoch is very slow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, mnist

Hi… I’m running mnist code in my P3 AWS machine and the initialization process seems to be very long compared to my previous P2 machine (although P3>P2)

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 265s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2674 - acc: 0.9175 - val_loss: 0.0602 - val_acc: 0.9811
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/step - loss: 0.0860 - acc: 0.9742 - val_loss: 0.0393 - val_acc: 0.9866
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 50us/step - loss: 0.0647 - acc: 0.9808 - val_loss: 0.0338 - val_acc: 0.9884
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 50us/step - loss: 0.0542 - acc: 0.9839 - val_loss: 0.0337 - val_acc: 0.9887
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 50us/step - loss: 0.0453 - acc: 0.9863 - val_loss: 0.0311 - val_acc: 0.9900
Epoch 6/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/step - loss: 0.0412 - acc: 0.9873 - val_loss: 0.0291 - val_acc: 0.9898
Epoch 7/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 50us/step - loss: 0.0368 - acc: 0.9891 - val_loss: 0.0300 - val_acc: 0.9901
Epoch 8/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 50us/step - loss: 0.0340 - acc: 0.9897 - val_loss: 0.0298 - val_acc: 0.9897
Epoch 9/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 50us/step - loss: 0.0320 - acc: 0.9908 - val_loss: 0.0267 - val_acc: 0.9916
Epoch 10/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 50us/step - loss: 0.0286 - acc: 0.9914 - val_loss: 0.0276 - val_acc: 0.9903
Test loss: 0.02757222411266339
Test accuracy: 0.9903
```

I’m using Keras=2.1.4
tensorflow-gpu=1.5.0

my keras.json file is configured as follows:

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

Any ideas why is it like that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6503):

> The first epoch takes the same time, but the counter also takes into
>   account the time taken by building the part of the computational graph
>   that deals with training (a few seconds). This used to be done during
>   the `compile` step, but now it is done lazily one demand to avoid
>   unnecessary work.

Comment: This could be one of the reasons. There is also data generating and caching in addition to kernel launching which could have bigger impact on the execution time. I am still trying to figure out a surge that sometimes happens while training. The answer was really helpful.